# No ScrollLeft on Android stock browser?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I'm trying to see if I can implement a rudimentary external scrollbar for an `overflow:scroll` box area and everything works on a browser on my computer and Firefox on the tablet, but it doesn't seem to work at all with the stock browser.

Is scrollLeft not supported? Is there any alternative that I can pursue?

Thanks!